# Vue complex prop mutation and one-way data flow

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I have searched around for this information but I'm not really sure how best to describe it so finding it from google searches has proved very difficult.

I write Vue applications a lot and I frequently run into the following situation where I have a complex object which I would like to pass into a child component via props so that I can encapsulate its mutation nicely and then have those changes mirrored in the parent component so that all of that information is in one place.

Consider the following simple example.

```js
// parent.vue
// list of complex objects in data
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tickets: [ 
        { name: "ticket 1", price: 20, quantity: 0 }, 
        { name: "ticket 2", price: 20, quantity: 0 }, 
        // etc
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// child.vue
// list passed from parent into props
export default {
  props: {
    tickets: Array
  }
}
```

To obey the Vue one-way data flow best practices, I should create a local copy of the `tickets` prop in child. I want the local copy to be updated if the parent mutates the `tickets` list for any reason, so I watch the `tickets` prop for changes and update the local copy accordingly:

```js
// child.vue
export default {
  props: {
    tickets: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      _tickets: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tickets: {
      handler: function (value) {
        // make deep local copy
        this._tickets = clone(value);
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
```

So now we have a local deep copy that we can make changes to without violating Vue's one-way data flow. I want all of my local changes to be reflected in the parent so I deep watch the local copy and emit the changed value back up to the parent. Props down, events up. Now my child component looks like this:

```js
// child.vue
export default {
  props: {
    tickets: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      _tickets: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tickets: {
      handler: function (value) {
        // make deep local copy
        this._tickets = clone(value);
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true
    },
    _tickets: {
      handler: function () {
        this.$emit('update:tickets', this._tickets); 
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
}
```

Now we run into an issue. This is an infinite loop because the `tickets` watcher mutates the `_tickets` property, invoking its watcher and mutating the parent value, invoking the `tickets` watcher... and so on. It might be possible (untested) to work around this issue by setting a flag on the `ticket` prop watcher so that the loop gets caught before re-emitting back up to the parent, but then this seems like a whole lot of unnecessary resources spent on creating copies just to conform with Vue best practices.

What is considered the correct approach to mutating complex object props?

Comment: Whenever I run into these types of issues it's a reason to start using state management libraries. Component A -> component B -> component C, component C changes info that A requires. Instead of bubbling it up its easier to change the state and have all components automatically change using a one-way flow of data. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/ for inspiration.

Comment: From child you could just emit an event with index of **ticket** and updated value, is not necessary to watch for **tickets** prop in child.

Comment: @Devilscomrade I have considered this but my application really isn't that complicated other than this one thing. I'd really like to avoid Vuex unless it's totally necessary.

Comment: Have you checked? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html . It has a simple implementation of state management without using any library. That might be a better option for you I guess

Comment: @KeerthiKumarP I had seen that before but I guess now might be a good time to try it out properly, thanks

Comment: "one way data flow" is overrated dogma in Vue community - just [my 2 cents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906727/381282)